# For My SQL 'Group By', what is the criteria of picking one row from many rows?

Tags: mysql, group-by

For My SQL 'Group By', what is the criteria of picking one row from many rows? For example if I use group by `user_id` would it choose the row in some order or in some random way? 
For example this table

```
id   user_id   message created_at

1     1         a      2016-08-25 07:00:15
2     2         c      2016-08-25 08:00:15
3     1         b      2016-08-25 09:46:15
4     2         d      2016-08-25 10:49:12
```

who will group by `user_id` find which row to take for user_id=1 row 1 or 3 because I could find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It will find the one specified in the aggregation (`MAX()`, `MIN()` etc.) statement, as you should only select grouped or aggregated columns when using `GROUP BY`.

Otherwise it is not determined which value will be chosen, it is pretty random.

Also see the MySQL manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If
>   the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default),
>   MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in
>   the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them.

So since MySQL 5.7 you explicitly have to enable an option so mysql can execute those queries.

Before MySQL 5.7 it allowed those queries but, as mentioned, chose the values of the nonaggegated and nongrouped fields randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Group by works on a specific `field`. If you group by `user_id` and `SELECT` any other column then `that column` from `that particular GROUP` will be selected randomly.

That is why it is not recommended to `SELECT` the field which is not in `GROUP BY` clause.

> who will group by user_id find which row to take for user_id=1 row 1
>   or 3 because i could find any solution.

Yes it will take other fields randomly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a query like

```
select user_id from yourtable group by user_id
```

then it does not matter from which record the values come from. However, if you have a query like

```
select user_id, created_at from yourtable group by user_id
```

where you have a field in the select list that is not subject of an aggregate function (max(), min(), etc), then as MySQL documentation on [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) says:

> In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.

In reality, MySQL will pick the value for such fields from the 1st record it encounters while assembling the resultset.

Pls alo note that unless such fields are functionally dependent on the fields in the group by, the query is against all sql standards. In MySQL you can use the [only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) sql mode setting (also part of the strict sql mode) to determine if MySQL accepts such queries at all. In the more recent versions of MySQL this qsl mode is turned on by default preventing you to run such queries without changing the settings.

Comment: *"In reality, MySQL will pick the value for such fields from the 1st record it encounters while assembling the resultset."* -- this is an implementation detail and not something to rely on. Further more, *"the 1st record it encounters"* doesn't mean a specified order and, in fact, removing that first row from the table and adding it again usually produces a different resultset returned by the invalid `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: I never said anyone should rely on the fact how MySQL picks the values for such fields. Pls do not give words in my mouth!

Comment: I didn't say you said that. However, that *"In reality"* tends to be interpreted by many beginners as a hint. I would reformulate to let the readers understand that it is just a coincidence and not something they should rely on.

Comment: Let's agree that we disagree. You interpret my message in one way, I in another way.

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` clause **does not** return rows from the database. It generates values using the rows filtered by the `WHERE` clause.

There are three types of columns that are **valid** in the expressions present in the `SELECT` clause of a query that contains a `GROUP BY` clause:

- columns that also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause;
- columns that are functionally dependent on the columns that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause;
- any column can be used as argument of a [`GROUP BY` aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

A `GROUP BY` query whose columns present in the `SELECT` clause do not follow the rules above is invalid SQL.

Up to version 5.7.5, MySQL allows invalid `GROUP BY` queries. It is [explained in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) that for the columns that do not follow the rules above, *"the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want."*

Since version 5.7.5 MySQL rejects such invalid queries. Other RDBMSes (SQL Server, Oracle etc) do not allow them too because, well, they are invalid SQL.

Comment: "Since version 5.7.5 MySQL rejects such invalid queries." No, this is not correct. MySQL's behaviour in this aspect depends on sql mode settings. In the older versions of MySQL such queries were allowed by the default settings, while in the more recent versions such queries are not allowed by the default settings (which is really good). But for all MySQL versions the behaviour is configurable.

Comment: You are right, it is configurable. But turning the strictness off doesn't magically make the invalid queries valid. They still return indeterminate results. The way to go is not to make newer MySQL versions behave the same as the older ones; the way to go is to write valid SQL queries that produce the same result no matter what implementation of SQL they run on.

Comment: Again, your putting words in my mouth I never said. All I pointed out that in MySQL it has always been up to the developer to decide whether such queries are allowed. Only the default behaviour of mysql has been changed.

Comment: I just explained why I did not mention anything in the answer about how to make MySQL accept bad queries even if I know how to do it.

Comment: The fact that you do not like a certain configuration option should not lead to providing a factually incorrect answer.